# Windows 7 product activation failed, but the previous activation code worked — is there anything to worry about?

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, lenovo-laptop, windows-activation, product-key

Alright, so there was a few reasons that made me have to reinstall Windows 7 onto my machine. I am running on a Lenovo Ideapad Y480. When Windows 7 was reinstalled, it asked me for my product activation code, and so I put in the one at the bottom of the computer.

Fast forward to where I am now, a few days later, and it says **my product activation failed and I need to put in a new one**.

I freaked out, but then tried to put in the **SAME product activation code** from the bottom of my computer, and it **successfully worked**. My only issue is I'm scared this will happen again and it will fail...**Can someone back me up with proof that if it happens again (or multiple times) that nothing bad will happen to my installation?**

And worst comes to worst, what will be disabled if my product key no longer works? And should I contact Lenovo/Microsoft to get the issue resolved in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't change the hardware (CPU, memory, harddrive), then it's most likely that somehow the key stored in registry is corrupted. It can be from a virus, misbehaving program, or a bad sector in the harddrive.

You can backup your activation token using [Advanced Tokens Manager](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/27341-Advanced-Tokens-Manager-The-Activation-Backup-Solution), so you won't need online activation (and it will work forever, the online method will require a phone call after several activation) but it will only work as long as the hardware isn't changed.